# Error using async/await in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, babeljs, ecmascript-next

When trying to use async/await in react-native, I am getting the following error:

```
    uncaught error Error: SyntaxError: /Users/senthilsivanath/Documents/MusicTulip/index.ios.js: Unexpected token (50:23)
  48 |   renderScene: function(route,nav) {
  49 |     try {
  50 |          const response = await signIn.isLoggedIn();
```

My `.babelrc` file is:

```
{ "presets": ["react-native", "es2015", "babel-preset-stage-3"] }
```

Answer (score 147, accepted):

**You might just be missing the `async` keyword on line 48.**

Update your code to use the `async` keyword before the `function` keyword:

```
renderScene: async function(route, nav) {
    try {
        const response = await signIn.isLoggedIn();
        // ...
```

Or when using an arrow function, put the `async` keyword before the parameter list:

```
 renderScene: async (route, nav) => {
        try {
            const response = await signIn.isLoggedIn();
```

In JavaScript, the `async` keyword is a decorator that warns the runtime that the attached enclosure will use the `await` keyword, so you always see them used together. Which is why you will hear people refer to this syntax as the `async/await` syntax.

**Simply put:** You can't use `await` without `async`.

**Edit:** If you are declaring this inside of a class, then just be sure that your [syntax is correct](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6901#issuecomment-208370580):

```
class MusicTulip extends Component {
    async renderContent() {
        const response = await signIn.isLoggedIn();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Did lot of permutation combination and it got removed.  Adding async also gives unexpected token error, source code updated

Comment: @MusicMan, I added a note about the syntax. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey thanks that works, but got next error

babelHelpers type of is not a function

babelHelpers.typeof(value) is undefined

Comment: To add to this, you can't make your constructor `async`. If you do some setup in the constructor, call an async method from there to put the logic in.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```js
const comp1 = await import('path');
```