# React with Axios, for the response I got from a GET, I want to use another GET, I want to sum up values from certain fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

New to React and Axios, trying to figure out how I can get this to work.

So from a React class I took, I learned that I should put the server call in `componentDidMount`, so my code looks like this:

```
state = {
    values : {}
}

componentDidMount () {
    axios.get(query_url, {headers:headers}).then(response => {
              //console.log(response.data.data[0]); 
              for (let i=0; i<response.data.data.length; i++) {
                  console.log(response.data.data[i]);
                  let data_url = some_url + response.data.data[i];
                  axios.get(data_url, {headers:headers}).then(response => {
                      for (let j=0; j<response.data.data[0]['metrics'].slice(0, 30).length; j++) {
                          let detail = response.data.data[0]['metrics'][j];
                          if (detail['country'] === 'US') {
                              usaVal += detail['value'];
                          } else {
                              worldVal += detail['value'];
                          }
                          this.setState({values: {usa: usaVal, world: worldVal}});
                      }
                  }
              }
        })
```

Let's assume all `some_url`, `headers`, `query_url` are all setup correctly (the line I commented out).

My goal is to get that final `usaVal` and `worldVal`, but as the data gets fetched, the state updates. How can I make sure I get the final number?

EDIT: following @Shubham Khatri 's suggestion, my code now looks like

```
async componentDidMount () {
    const url = "some url";
    const queryUrl = url + "some other crap";
    const headers = {"auth": "some auth"};

    //first level: get query params
    const response = axios.get(queryUrl, {headers: headers});
    if (response) {
      response.then(response => {
        const data = await Promise.all(response.map((data, index) => axios.get(`${url}${data}`, {headers: headers})));
        console.log(data);
      })
    }
```

Now I'm getting `Syntax error: await is a reserved word`

From [Error using async/await in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527490/error-using-async-await-in-react-native/36532046#36532046)  I need `async` to go with `await`, which I have. Am I not using it correctly?

Comment: does it not work, what error do you get

Comment: sorry I was editing my question. The original post was wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use `async-await` with `Promise.all`

```
async componentDidMount () {
    const response = await axios.get(query_url, {headers:headers})
    //console.log(response.data.data[0]); 
    if(response) {
        const data = await Promise.all(response.data.data
            .map((data, index) => axios.get(`${some_url}${data}`, {headers:headers})
        ))

        // handle responses
        let usaVal = 0, worldVal = 0;
        data.forEach(response => {
            for (let j=0; j<response.data.data[0]['metrics'].slice(0, 30).length; j++) {
                let detail = response.data.data[0]['metrics'][j];
                if (detail['country'] === 'US') {
                    usaVal += detail['value'];
                } else {
                    worldVal += detail['value'];
                }      
            }
        })
        this.setState({values: {usa: usaVal, world: worldVal}});
     }
}
```

Comment: sorry can you explain how you get `(data, index)` and if the `data_url` after `some_url` should be `response.data.data` instead? I'm quite confused on the .map() part of this example

Comment: Instead of using a for loop over `response.data.data`, we use a map which gives the data object and the index as parameters in the callback function, so `response.data.data[i]` is data and `let data_url = some_url + response.data.data[i];` is equivalent to `${some_url}${data}`

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. When I tried it, I got `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined` do you know why? This is just for the line `const data = await Promise.all(response.data.data
            .map((data, index) => axios.get(`${some_url}${data}`, {headers:headers})
        ))`

Comment: Okay, my response is empty, the `data.data` shows up in `PromiseValue`. it seems like I need a `.then`?

Comment: Check the update, `const response = await axios.get(query_url, {headers:headers})`

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: Glad to have helped