# reactjs :Parsing error: await is a reserved word

Tags: javascript, async-await

./src/App.js

> Line 15:  Parsing error: await is a reserved word

```
13 |   getWeather = async=()=>{
14 | 
15 |     const api_call = await fetch('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Manchester,uk&appid=${API_KEY}');
   |                      ^
16 | 
17 |     const data = await api_call.json();
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error using async/await in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527490/error-using-async-await-in-react-native)

Comment: The extraneous `=` sign after `async` is probably ruining your function.

Comment: The error is in the syntax of your function, you have an extra `=` between async and function 

    getWeather = async ()=>{

Answer (score 2):

Since you're new to this language, I suggest you don't use this way. That's called `arrow function`.

```
async () => { /*...*/ };

// same to

async function () { /*...*/ };
```

And use it with parameter(s):

```
async (param_1, param_2) => { /*...*/ };

// same to

async function (param_1, param_2) { /*...*/ };
```

In your case, the problem may come from

```
// remove "=" character after "async" keyword here
async=()=> { /*...*/ }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Do you think that people new to js shouldn't use arrow functions?

Comment: @OliverRadini Yes sir! For me, we need to learn how to define a function using general syntax first. Then, we can start with arrow function. From ES5 to ES6.

Comment: I think perhaps I disagree, the syntax of the arrow function does not seem to be the issue here. I'm not sure the syntax of arrow functions is necessarily more difficult to understand than that of a standard function definition

Comment: @OliverRadini Agree! It's just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you have an unnecessary `=` symbol. The async keyword doesn't need an `=` symbol after it, you might think of it as a sort of 'label' for the function. Because the function isn't correctly labelled as `async`, the code doesn't like there being an `await` keyword in the body of the function.

Here are some snippets to demonstrate the difference:

```js
const getWeather = async=()=>{ 
 const api_call = await fetch('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Manchester,uk&appid=${API_KEY}');
 
  const data = await api_call.json();
}
```

The code above is trying to set both `getWeather` and `async` to be the function you define. Here are some more examples to demonstrate:

```js
const test = aNonKeyword = () => {
  console.log('test')
}

const testTwo = anotherNonKeyword = 'A Test String'

var var1 = var2 = var3 = 1

console.log(test)
console.log(aNonKeyword)
console.log(testTwo)

console.log(var1)
console.log(var2)
console.log(var3)
```

...and here's the actual, working version:

```js
const getWeather = async () => { 
 const api_call = await fetch('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Manchester,uk&appid=${API_KEY}');
 
  const data = await api_call.json();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 13 is trying to reassign an arrow function to the reserved variable "async". Most likely a typo, one key to remember in J's is the right to left execution.